# Best way to deliver a website to view offline on an Android tablet

Tags: android, html, air, web, offline

looking for some advice on what is the best way to deliver an HTML/CSS based website for use on Android tablets offline.

Having researched the topic on here for a while and looking into different development techniques there seems to be two outright 'winners' as such for delivering such a project.

Firstly, is to build the website normally and then save it to an SD Card to run in the Android browser, secondly is to use Adobe Air and run as an Android app but what I'd also like to know is whether if it is possible to browse the website online and have it cache on to the device so that when it loses an internet connection the full website will still run as normal.

A bit more info on the website, it will be built completely in HTML/CSS with responsive templates so that resolutions aren't an issue and it is a 'brochure' website so the content won't need updated at any point.

Any help on the issue is much appreciated as developing Android apps or running websites from an SD Card is something I've not had the pleasure of doing before.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native
>   applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app
>   stores.
>
> Say goodbye to SDKs, compilers and hardware. Simply write your app
>   using HTML, CSS or JavaScript, upload it to the PhoneGap Build service
>   and get back app-store ready apps for Apple iOS, Google Android, Palm,
>   Symbian, BlackBerry and more.
>
> By compiling in the cloud with PhoneGap Build, you get all the
>   benefits of cross-platform development but can still build apps just
>   the way you like.

You can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and even [Build PhoneGap](https://build.phonegap.com/) (online version) - just upload your entire HTML5 app as a ZIP folder (local paths like /assets/ and not D:/images/) - just the full app code and zip it - then use PhoneGap - it will convert it and give you the App code file - visit Android marketplace as well as others such as Apple and upload.

done.

Comment: So create your responsive fluid site, then upload and it will fit cross ready. Everyone is happy.

Comment: No problem. It really is brilliant, especially for web devs. You find a lot of creative front end talent out there but people scared to use mobile app scene due to lack of cocoa, c# and other mobile platform programming like Java. HTML5 (be it CSS3, canvas, storage or pure HTML5 code and some jQuery) mixed in with Phonegap, you can turn your offline site to a full blow mobile app.